# missing column in Heroku db after delete add_column file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I created add_column migration to add column name "admin" in users table. But i Accedintly deleted the file and push my code to Heroku and did db:migrate. Now when inmy local machine admin exists but when I tested in production I cant see admin column in users table. I tried again to push and migrate but noting is workig. Here is my code:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|

   t.string "username"
   t.string "email"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.string "password_digest"
   t.boolean "admin", default: false

end
```

Heroku rails console when I run User:

```
User(id: integer, username: string, email: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, password_digest: string)
```

local console when I run User:

```
 => User(id: integer, username: string, email: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, password_digest: string, admin: boolean
```

Thank you and this is my second month of learning rails :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just make the same "mistake" again but in reverse. The first thing to do is to remove the column from your local database...

```
$ rails g migration remove_admin_from_users admin:boolean
$ rails db:migrate
```

Then, delete the migration file that was generated.

Now, you start fresh and can run

```
$ rails g migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean
$ rails db:migrate
```

Then, push to Github and Heroku to get your development and production environments back in sync.

Don't forget to run...

```
$ heroku run rails db:migrate
```

Comment: i just did the mistake and got a new error  column "admin" of relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" DROP COLUMN "admin"

Comment: In what environment? Development or production (Heroku)?

Comment: when I run heroku run rails db:migrate

Comment: Did you remove the migration file that was generated when you removed the admin column? More specifically, the last file in `db/migrate`?

Comment: I didn't remove anything. The only file I removed was add_column_admin yesterday. should I remove it ?

Comment: Remove that file locally then push to github and heroku again. The issue is that it's trying to remove a column that doesn't exist in your production database. By "that file" I mean delete the last file in your `db/migrate` directory where you dropped the admin column on the users table.